# Independent marginals and radial symmetry implies normality?

Tags: probability

If a multivariate distribution is radially symmetric and its marginals are mutually independent, then it must be normal.

Does the same hold if the marginals are merely pairwise independent?

Comment: Neat Theorem to start off with.  Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: No I don't, sorry. It's pretty quick to establish in the 2D case by setting $f(x) f(y) = g(x^2 + y^2)$, switching to polar coordinates, differentiating with respect to $\theta$, and rearranging into the ODE for the Gaussian. Unless I'm missing something silly, essentially the same argument holds in higher dimensions (by switching to cylindrical coordinates) to show that $f$ satisfies $f'(x) \propto x f(x)$. I'm pretty sure it's direct and what I said above suffices, but I'm also terrified of making a mistake in front of the entire internet, so perhaps I should edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Here we go, I found one. See the first sentence of the abstract: http://www.orga.cvss.cc/media/publications/SinzGerwinnBethge_2008.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much for following up with a reference.  Cool to see this is due to Kac.  I've previously found myself enjoying his work again and again.  Cheers.